# C++ modulus operator with float using #define and own class

Tags: c++

C++ modulus operator with float.
I know modulus % operator can be used only with both operands being integers and in case one is trying to use floats it causes compilation error.

```
error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double'
```

However i am in certain scenario where I do not have control and code doing float % float resulting in compilation issues.
Hence I tried to create my own dbl minimalist class to achieve the same .

```
// testMod.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"
class DBL{

public:
    bool lastError;
    float dbl;
    DBL()
    {
        dbl = 0.0;
    }
    DBL(float b)
    {
        dbl = b;
    }
    /*float operator % (float t)
    {
        return fmod(dbl, t);
    }*/
    operator float()
    {
        return dbl;
    }

    friend float operator % (DBL a, DBL b);
};


float operator % (DBL a, DBL b)
{
    return fmod(a.dbl, b.dbl);
}



#define  float DBL

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    float temp;
    float a = 3.24;
    float b = 4.32;
    temp = a % b ;
    temp = 0;
    temp = a % b;
    temp = 3.14 % 5.01; // compilation error here
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile . I was hoping to use the implicit conversion but it seems it didn't do that . Also is a minimalist conversion adequate if one is handling ONLY % oneself and depending on default conversion for everything else ?

Comment: Why not use the function `fmod()`, which is declared in the standard header `<cmath>` (or in the C header `<math.h>`)?

Comment: You are just going to have to *take* control. Otherwise nothing will compile.

Comment: You cannot overload operators between built-in types and you can't have them implicitly convert either. There is no way to work around the fact that someone produced ill-formed code besides rewriting it.

Comment: There's the minor problem that `3.14` is not even a `float`. It's a `double`. Minor, because `3.14f % 5.01f` causes the same error. But the oversight reinforces my impression that you're not really familar with C++.

Comment: Why would there be code that doesn't work, that you can't change? That makes no sense. Unless in reality there are templates involved??

Answer (score -1):

I think you should convert the values to be integers so the input will be supported. `(int)foo` is the simplest conversion, but it might be less than adequate for you. If it does not fulfill your needs, then you will need to write your own custom conversion. If this approach does not solve your problem, then you will need to modify the source-code of the library (by reverse-engineering if legal and necessary), or, if that's not an option, ask the author to use `fmod` in the library. Your idea is clever, but unfortunately that's not how things work.